# URLSessionDownloadTask Progressbar с несколькими загрузками

Tags: ios, swift

Я делаю загрузку фотографий и аудио из url
Делаю я это так

```
extension DownloadAllViewController:  URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    //        print("downloadLocation:", location)
    // create destination URL with the original pdf name
    guard let url = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url else { return }
    let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let destinationURL = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
    // delete original copy
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationURL)
    // copy from temp to Document
    do {
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: location, to: destinationURL)
            print(destinationURL)



    } catch let error {
        print("Copy Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}}
```

Само сохранение

```
guard let url_audio_qq = URL(string: "url") else { return }
let urlSession1 = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self as URLSessionDelegate, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())

let downloadTask1 = urlSession1.downloadTask(with: url_audio_qq)

downloadTask1.resume()
```

А вот как заполняется прогрессбар

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
    //        if totalBytesExpectedToWrite > 0 {
    let progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.progressBar.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
        self.per_cents.text = "\(Int(progress*100))%"
    }
}
```

Сейчас у меня после каждой загрузки отдельного аудио или изображения заполняется шкала, после того как аудио скачалось, она опять спадает до нуля и показывает прогресс загрузки следуйщего
Как сделать так чтобы он выводил прогресс от общей загрузки всех файлов, а не по отдельности каждого файла?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Простое решение**

Наверное Вы знаете количество URL, которые планируется загрузить (`let urlsCount`). В таком случае можно сохранять количество загруженных объектов (`var loadedURLsCount`)

```swift
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    loadedURLsCount += 1
    ...
}
```

и немного поменять формулу подчета прогресса:

```swift
let progress = (Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite) + loadedURLsCount) / urlsCount
```

**Решение с поддержкой одновременной загрузки файлов**

Если планируется поддержка одновременных загрузок, то формула становится сложнее, ведь надо учитывать прогресс в каждой загрузке. Стоит вынести логику в отдельный объект:

```swift
struct ProgressTracker {
    // Стуктура для сохранения информации о каждой из загрузок
    struct Item {
        var expectedSize: Int64
        var downloadedSize: Int64
    }

    // Список всех загрузок
    private var items: [Item]

    init(count: Int) {
        assert(count > 0)
        items = Array(repeating: Item(expectedSize: 0, downloadedSize: 0), count: count)
    }

    // Метод для задания ожидаемого размера загрузки
    mutating func setExpectedSize(_ size: Int64, for index: Int) {
        items[index].expectedSize = size
    }

    mutating func setDownloadedSize(_ size: Int64, for index: Int) {
        items[index].downloadedSize = size
    }

    // Подсчет суммарного прогресса загрузки
    var progress: Float {
        return items.map { $0.progress }.reduce(0, +) / Float(items.count)
    }

}

// Подсчет прогресса загрузки одного элемента
private extension ProgressTracker.Item {
    var progress: Float {
        guard expectedSize > 0 else { return 0 }
        return Float(downloadedSize) / Float(expectedSize)
    }
}
```

Далее вы можете сохранить этот в `DownloadAllViewController`, менять в нем значения ожидаемого размера файла и загруженного размера. В `didSet` этого объекта можно изменять отображаемое значение.

```swift
var progressTracker = ProgressTracker(count: 10) {
    didSet {
        self.progressBar.setProgress(progressTracker.progress, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам, это то что нужно